# Is there a way to include a terminal in my Office add-in?

Tags: office-js

The MSFT Script Lab add-in for Outlook includes a terminal below to check things like console.logs, anyone know how to include in a task-pane react add-in? Generated the template using yo office.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Script Lab is open source, so you could copy the code (subject to the licensing requirements): [script-lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab)